# Customize the listing in vtiger CRM

Tags: customization, crm, vtiger

I want to customize my listing of plan's tasks. I have edited RelatedListView.php under modules/Vtiger/models

But I was failed.
Exactly I want to add a new link in the listing. All the related links are coming in the current listing but I want to show the document related to the tasks individually.

Let me know if anyone has faced this issue already or got solved from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at showing the related task attached to the document?

I had this problem where I wanted the document to have a link to the connected task. To do this I used a plugin called [VGSRelatedFields](http://www.vgsglobal.com/blog/vtiger-related-fields/)

Give that a go.